# Memory consumed quickly on my server

Tags: linux, centos6

Recently I notice the memory on my Linux server(CentOS 6.8) is consumed quickly. Yesterday I restart my server, and then use free to check the memory, and it reports about 30GB free among 32GB memory.

However, after one day, the free memory is reduced to 12GB.

Is that normal?

I try to use top -a command and get the following result:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                   
 3083 mysql     20   0 2799m 290m  14m S  6.6  0.9  59:50.83 mysqld                                                                                                     
 6193 root      20   0  253m 134m 3684 S  0.0  0.4   0:06.62 spamd child                                                                                                
 2665 root      20   0  245m 128m 5276 S  0.0  0.4   0:09.47 spamd                                                                                                      
 6194 root      20   0  245m 125m 1452 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.02 spamd child                                                                                                
18201 datanu5   20   0  520m  93m  14m S  0.0  0.3   0:01.18 php-cgi                                                                                                    
19861 datanu5   20   0  517m  91m  15m S 16.3  0.3   0:00.49 php-cgi                                                                                                    
 1531 root      20   0 1346m  47m 9316 S  0.0  0.1   0:41.05 backup_runner.p                                                                                            
 9745 nobody    20   0 2472m  37m  10m S  0.7  0.1   0:27.42 httpd                                                                                                      
 9492 nobody    20   0 2471m  37m  10m S  0.7  0.1   0:26.90 httpd                                                                                                      
 9618 nobody    20   0 2535m  37m  10m S  0.7  0.1   0:27.53 httpd                                                                                                      
 9681 nobody    20   0 2472m  36m  10m S  0.3  0.1   0:27.14 httpd                                                                                                      
 9556 nobody    20   0 2469m  36m  10m S  0.3  0.1   0:27.74 httpd                                                                                                      
19862 datanu5   20   0  461m  33m  13m S  2.3  0.1   0:00.07 php-cgi                                                                                                    
 2348 root      20   0  160m  28m 2056 S  0.0  0.1   0:06.64 lfd - sleeping                                                                                             
 1343 nobody    20   0 2470m  27m 5324 S  0.3  0.1   0:10.38 httpd                                                                                                      
 3561 root      20   0  109m  25m 6780 S  0.0  0.1   0:16.16 cpsrvd (SSL) -                                                                                             
 3213 root      20   0  217m  19m  10m S  0.0  0.1   0:04.93 httpd                                                                                                      
 3581 root      20   0 54132  13m 2940 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.74 tailwatchd                                                                                                 
 9491 root      20   0 52316  11m 2344 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.06 leechprotect                                                                                               
 9490 nobody    20   0  217m 8844  548 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd                                                                                                      
 3155 mailnull  20   0 77020 8308 4048 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.94 exim                                                                                                       
 3567 root      20   0 43344 7584 2388 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.36 queueprocd - wa                                                                                            
 2622 root      20   0  196m 5632 1444 S  0.0  0.0   0:08.73 snmpd                                                                                                      
 3875 root      20   0  431m 5312 2496 S  0.0  0.0   0:11.63 dsm_sa_datamgrd                                                                                            
 3167 dovenull  20   0 45672 4380 3236 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.33 imap-login                                                                                                 
 3166 dovenull  20   0 45528 4292 3192 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.96 pop3-login                                                                                                 
 3162 dovenull  20   0 45520 4240 3200 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.11 pop3-login 
...
```

It seems there are no special process that consume memory a lot, why the free memory is reduced so quickly?

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: @ceejayoz, Thank you very much. Now it seems my system memory allocation is OK.